# Inverting forecolor (text color) based on back color in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to choose a text color based on background color `hex` in Ruby. For example:

User inputted this back color:

[image: color1]

Then **expected** text color should be white `#FFFFFF` (white).

If user choose something similar to this:

[image: color2]

Then **expected** text color should be `#000000` (black)

I know this is possible and I found similar code samples for other languages such as JavaScript or c# but they are all based on `RGB`. I cannot port to `HEX` in ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pratha, I have taken the same approach as you; I've just organized the calculations a little differently.

The W3C has developed a measure of the [perceived brightness of any colour](https://www.w3.org/TR/AERT/#color-contrast): `(299*r + 114*b + 587*g)/1000`, where `r`, `b` and `g` are each between `0` and `0xFF`. The maximum value is found to be `255`.

We can define a method that expresses brightness of a colour as a fraction of the brightness of white:

```
WHITE_BRIGHT = 299*0xFF + 114*0xFF + 587*0xFF
  #=> 255000

def brightness(rbg)
  rb,g = rbg.divmod(0x100)
  r,b  = rb.divmod(0x100)
  (299*r + 114*b + 587*g).fdiv(WHITE_BRIGHT)
end

brightness 0         #=> 0.0 
brightness 0xFFFFFF  #=> 1.0 
brightness 0x668899  #=> 0.5326 
brightness 0xFFEFF8  #=> 0.9767... 
brightness 0x1F223F  #=> 0.1965...
```

See [Integer#divmod](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Integer.html#method-i-divmod) (a very useful method) and [Integer#fdiv](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Integer.html#method-i-fdiv).

We simply choose a background colour to maximize the difference between the foreground and background brightness. That will obviously be black or white, depending on whether `brightness(rgb)` is more than than `0.5`.

```
def background(rbg)
  brightness(rbg) > 0.5 ? 0 : 0xFFFFFF
end

background(0).to_s(16)         #=> "ffffff" 
background(0xFFFFFF).to_s(16)  #=> "0" 
background(0x668899).to_s(16)  #=> "0" 
background(0xFFEFF8).to_s(16)  #=> "0" 
background(0x1F223F).to_s(16)  #=> "ffffff"
```

Comment: @Sergio, ah, yes, so I see.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to do one with myself. Please correct me if this is wrong or can result unexpected results for specific colors.

```
def colorize(hex)
    r = hex[0..1].to_i(16)
    g = hex[2..3].to_i(16)
    b = hex[4..5].to_i(16)
    c = ((r*299)+(g*587)+(b*114))/1000
    (c >= 128) ? :black : :white
end


puts colorize '668899'
# => :white 
puts colorize 'ffefe8'
# => :black
```

Comment: I mean user can choose whatever color they want from millions of possibilities. And I need to always make sure the text is always visible to selected backcolor.